# How to parse this string of latitude/longitude coordinates in java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, format

I have a string, pointString.

and I'm trying to get the number values from them and add them to new LatLng variables.

Heres my code

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> ConvertPoints (String pointsStringInput){
        ArrayList <LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        String pointsString = pointsStringInput.substring(1, pointsStringInput.length()-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < pointsString.split("lat/lng: ").length; i++){
            Log.w("INDEX", String.valueOf(i));
            if (!pointsString.split("lat/lng: ")[i].matches("none12323232321412515152124214412")){
                points.add(new LatLng (Double.parseDouble(pointsString.split("lat/lng: ")[i].split(",")[0].replace("\\(", "")), Double.parseDouble(pointsString.split("lat/lng: ")[i].split(",")[1].replace("\\)", ""))));
            }
        }
        return points;

    }
```

it always crashes on I=0, with java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: Please save your computing, you did `pointsString.split("lat/lng: ")` 4 times ;)

Comment: Share class LatLng also  please.

Answer (score 2):

You did use `pointsString.split("lat/lng: ")` 4 times, but never print it out, but it values the following. As you split you got the parts that are before and after the delimiter, so you have the empty content before the first one.

```
[, (43.8457509,-79.45568817), , (43.8457509,-79.45568817), , (43.84598041,-79.45584389), , (43.845954,-79.45585094]
```

---

The easier whould be to use regular expression, as you know perfectly how the data should be `lat/lng: \((-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)\)`

- `\(` and `\)` to match the real parenthesis
- `-?` to match eventually a minus
- `\d+\.\d+` to match the values
- `lat/lng: \(-?\d+\.\d+,-?\d+\.\d+\)` final regex, then just add `()` for capturing the values

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> ConvertPoints(String pointsStringInput) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("lat/lng: \\((-?\\d+\\.\\d+),(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)").matcher(pointsStringInput);
    while (m.find()) {
        points.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)), Double.parseDouble(m.group(2))));
    }
    return points;
}
```

---

The version with `Stream<MatchResult>` is

```
private List<LatLng> ConvertPoints(String pointsStringInput) {
    return Pattern.compile("lat/lng: \\((-?\\d+\\.\\d+),(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)")
            .matcher(pointsStringInput).results()
            .map(m -> new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)), Double.parseDouble(m.group(2))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: @user85421-Banned Yep I don't want to split, we may have the same problem as the first split